# How to check the residuals of a ARIMA-ARCH model?

Tags: r, arima, garch, arma, arch

Lets say we have a AR(1)-ARCH(1) time series model and we want to check the residuals for Ljung-Box. If the residuals of the model is `Fit@residuals` (using `R` for modeling) and the variance of the model is `Fit@Sigma` Is it true that the real residuals that we should check is `Fit@residuals/Fit@Sigma` ? since from Box et al. 2008 we have:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an ARMA-GARCH model it is the *standardized* residuals that should be i.i.d., non-autocorrelated and conditionally homoskedastic, and have the distribution that was assumed when forming the likelihood function of the model. That is not the *raw* residuals from the ARMA model $a_t$ (following the notation above) but the *standardized* residuals $e_t$ (as implicitly defined in the equation 10.1.3).

It seems you may be using "fGarch" package in R. Then `@residuals` will yield $a_t$ as the "fGarch" package [pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fGarch/fGarch.pdf) says on p. 13: "a numeric vector with the (raw, unstandardized) residual values". Then $e_t$ could indeed be obtained as `Fit@residuals/Fit@sigma.t`; it is $e_t$ that should be the input for tests for presence of autocorrelation, remaining ARCH effects etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer just to be clear I am actually using `garchfit` and `garchinfer` functions in `MATLAB` but I used these notions since most of people know R here. By any chance do you know that the residuals that I get from `garchinfer` function is the same as the '@residuals' from "fGarch" in R?

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not use Matlab. I suppose there should be some help files stating clearly what is what in Matlab.